# In the kernel space, how does one get the physical addresses corresponding to a file on ext4-formatted disk

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, paging

If you're here:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ext4/file.c#L360 

You have access to these two structs inside the `ext4_file_mmap` function:

```
struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma
```

I am changing the implementation of this function for `dax` mode so that the page tables get entirely filled out for the file the moment you call `mmap` (to see how much better performance not taking any `pagefaults` gives us).

I have managed to get the following done so far (assuming I have access to to the two structs that `ext4_file_mmap` has access to):

```
// vm_area_struct defined in /include/linux/mm_types.h : 284
// file defined in /include/linux/fs.h : 848

loff_t file_size = file_inode(file)->i_size;
unsigned long start_va = vma->vm_start;
```

Now, the difficulty lies here. How do I get the physical addresses (blocks? Not sure if `dax` uses blocks) associated with this file?

I have spent the last couple of days staring at the linux source code, trying to make sense of stuff, and boy have I been successful.

Any help, hint,or  suggestion is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Some updates: When you `mmap` a file in `dax` mode, you don't fetch anything into memory. The device, in this case PMEM, is byte-addressable and gives DDR latencies, so it's accessed directly (no memory in between). Certain `pte`s lead to the access of this PMEM device instead of memory.

Comment: This is proobably the wrong place to do it though...

Comment: Why don't you just pin the virtual address corresponding to the `mmap` memory? It will automatically fetch the pages from disk (or whatever device) and avoid any page faults in user/kernel mode.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Can you let me know where you think I should start, please? Also, I mean to fill out the `pte` only for files that are `mmap`ed, not for the entire PMEM device, if that was causing any misunderstanding.

Comment: Also, *to see if not taking any pagefaults gives us better performance in PMEM* this is kind of guaranteed if you are going to read all the content from the file. No page fault is better an 1 page fault per page.

Comment: @peanutlover sorry, I am not *that much* of Linux kernel expert, just saying that it would be a bit ugly to start filling the page table exactly *in* there... Also, have you experimented with `madvise` flags yet?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I agree. I should be more specific. We want to see _how much better_ it is. Also, I don't completely get what _pin_ is, but from the looks of it, it seems to bring pages into memory and lock it there. In `dax` mode, you don't bring the stuff in memory. You access the device directly without any memory access (the device is byte-addressable and gives DDR latencies). Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @peanutlover pin doesn't just bring the content to the memory. Depending on the type of the physical address, it creates mapping in the page table. It just basically gives you the guarantee that there won't be a page fault on any access on the pages which are pinned. I think that is what you are trying to do too. You are trying to force insert all the mappings in the page table.

Comment: @peanutlover There is a minor flaw with your logic though (I think). The OS doesn't guarantee that these mappings will remain forever. The OS can chose to evict the mapping ( although I can't think of any reason why it would do so since there is no RAM involved/consumed here). But pinning gives you the guarantee until you explicitly unpin.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks for the suggestion! I looked into it, and, wow, TIL something awesome! I'll probably go through and read it's source code. Maybe that'll help. Using `madvise` flags I don't think would be helpful in this case. I have updated the question with more details (which the comment above reiterates). Essentially, I am not fetching anything into memory. I just need the page tables completely filled out.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya That sounds very, very promising! Thanks! I'll look more into it and update my findings tomorrow!

Comment: @peanutlover worst case, you can look the Page fault handler. Since it has to create the mapping and you can pick up the code from there.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I actually went down that route first. I forgot why, but I got stuck somewhere. One of the functions that pagefault handler eventually ended up calling had access to some data that I didn't have access to I think... Not sure. I might have to go down that path again. Anyways, will keep you updated.

Comment: @peanutlover I did not think of this before, but why don't you simply fault into all the pages once by reading 1 byte per page in `mmap` itself (if that doesn't break semantics for your device) ? Here you don't have to reimplement any functionality?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yeah. We've a new memory allocator, too, so it could be like a config in it or something. But it's not upto me unfortunately.

Comment: @peanutlover Yes, it can be done from user space too. You don't need any kernel changes.

Comment: I guess we care about that overhead since this will likely be going in a very extensively used Redis environment.

Comment: @peanutlover I think something like adjusting `MADV_WILLNEED` or creating a similar flag, would be something you'd need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all mmap support MAP_POPULATE flag specifically to avoid page faults. In principle it may be it does not work with dax, but that's unlikely.

Second of all it seems you don't have any measurements of the current state of affairs. Just "changing something and checking the difference" is a fundamentally wrong approach. In particular it may be the actual bottleneck will be removed as an unintended consequence of the change and the win will end up being misattributed. You can start by using 'perf' to get basic numbers and generating flamegraphs ( http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html ). If you do a lot of i/o over a small range, page faults should have a negligible effect.

Comment: First things first, I like your username! It suits you. You have saved me quite a bit of trouble.

Comment: Yep. I agree with your second point, but in this case I think pre-loading `pte`s shouldn't lead to performance mis-attribution. I'll keep your point in mind and be careful, though! Thanks for reminding me!